# Django: Message is not receieving

Tags: django

I am using [Django Postman](https://bitbucket.org/psam/django-postman/src)   for the intercommunication between two user of my django website .

But when i am sending a message to another user .It is not delivered  to the recepient .

I shows  me as sent message .In `http://127.0.0.1:8000/messages/sent`

Here is `settings.py` setting

```
#############################   Django postman 

POSTMAN_AUTO_MODERATE_AS = True
POSTMAN_SHOW_USER_AS = True
POSTMAN_NOTIFIER_APP = True
###################################
```

And once the messages is sent it is storing properly in the Dtabase but it is not appearing to the recepient inbox.

Please tell me what might I am doing wrong here .

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered seemingly identical problem, in my case cause was default moderation.

**To better diagnose if this is the case**, you can:

- check your 'invisible' messages in database, for example using phpmyadmin. If there's 'p' as m moderation_status or anything suspicious under moderation_... columns, this track is probably good;
- dig into code: locate postman/models.py and experiment with class MessageManager, method inbox (since other message directories are fine, this one is suspicious). Any of filters there might be cause of your problem - for me it was obviously 'moderation_status'. Even if your case is different, this is good starting point for further debugging.

**Use case: let's assume moderation issues**

I see that you have

```
POSTMAN_AUTO_MODERATE_AS = True
```

set, but perhaps you have left moderation function somewhere, or something gets overwritten in your configuration? Postman's Quick Start Guide indicates that both are necessary:

> To disable the moderation feature (no control, no filter):
>
> > - Set this option to True
> > - Do not provide any auto-moderation functions

I'd suggest removing all other postman specific options from your settings.py, leaving only POSTMAN_AUTO_MODERATE_AS = True and check if there are any utility functions that could potentially interfere with Message objects.

For further reference, more information about moderation is here: https://bitbucket.org/psam/django-postman/wiki/Moderation